# Is there a way to extract a string while parsing using Scala combinators?

Tags: regex, scala, parsing, parser-combinators

I have a language which accepts similar strings to this: `!A(){assertion}`.
I want assertion to be considered as a string without `" "`, meaning that instead of `assertion` anything can be placed. I am currently using the parser combinators in Scala, and for the assertion part I am using a Regex function as below:

```
def regex ( r: Regex ): Parser[String] = new Parser[String] {
    def apply ( in: Input )
    = r.findPrefixMatchOf(in.source.subSequence(in.offset,in.source.length)) match {
      case Some(matched) =>
        Success(matched.group(1).toString, in.drop(in.offset+matched.end-1))
      case None => Failure("string matching regex `"+r+"' expected but "+in.first+" found",in)
    }
}
```

However, I have an issue because the drop function of the Input takes as parameter the number of ***elements*** that should be dropped from the beginning. The issue is that the number of elements taken out by the regex function is unknown.

*Example*
If I have: `!A(){num >= count}` and using the regex function I extract `num >= count`, in total I would have extracted 3 elements. Therefore, I need to drop those 3 elements from the input, i.e. it should return: `Success(matched.group(1).toString, in.drop(3))`. However, I cannot find a way to know the number of elements to be dropped from the input.

Comment: If you need to fix the regex, add it to the question, and make it clear.

Comment: What I mean by the regex function is the actual function parsing the regex, i.e. the code pasted above.